# M1 Mac - Flutter - unable to run projects on physical or simulated devices

Tags: java, android, flutter, apple-m1

Flutter installed, no problems, Java installed. Physical devices appear when connected but when I run the project I get the following message

"Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x637d2aaf) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x637d2aaf"

I've looked at previous similar questions that suggested re-installing java. Done that.
Simulators(android) don't work either. iOS simulator works fine. Could be unrelated I Know. Seems to be something to do with permissions but I'm a newby and have spent hours trying to solve it alone. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to run from terminal